# No me funcionan las rutas en angular

Tags: angular, angular8

Resulta que no me funcionan las rutas en angular.

Este es mi archivo **app.routes.ts**:

```
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [

    {path:'navbar', component: NavbarComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }

    //{path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'}
];

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

y este es mi archivo **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {APP_ROUTING} from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    APP_ROUTING
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Este es mi **home.component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Si yo por ejemplo meto en el navegador http://localhost:4200/home se me muestra la página en blanco completamente

el contenido de mi  **app.component.html** es:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Soy nuevo en angular y no doy con las solución por más que he repasado esos archivos. Muchas gracias de antemano!

Mi estructura de archivos es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Mi versión de angular es la "Angular: 8.2.14".

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.20
@angular/cli                      8.3.20
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.20
@schematics/angular               8.3.20
@schematics/update                0.803.20
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Adjunto el error que me da:

> compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>       'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>
> [ERROR ->]
>
> "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:0
>           at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
>           at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11388)
>           at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25963)
>           at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25951)
>           at compiler.js:25895
>           at Set.forEach ()
>           at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
>           at compiler.js:25808
>           at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
>           at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)

---

```
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Gracias, pero he añadido esa linea y no funciona...

Comment: Te recomiendo que actualices el CLI de Angular, ya estamos en la version 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que veo que que no estas importando el `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` en tu  `app.routes` y al parecer por eso no te esta funcionando. lo demás veo que esta funcionando bien. hice un  ejemplo en stackblitz te lo dejo para que lo cheques, des-comente `path: '**'` para que mostrara el contenido del home.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routers-demo?file=src/app/app.routes.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes subir el proyecto a github?
Puedes probar de la siguiente manera

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Quitamos en navbar por si da problemas.
En **app.modules.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.